# How to manually install AndroidImage_x86_API25 from visual studio Xamarin Installer

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Xamarin extension for my Visual Studio Professional 2017. However, the installation gets hung up when it gets to "Acquiring AndroidImage_x86_API25." I am receiving an error message saying it tried 9 times but could not download the component.

I went to the link it provided and it directed me to the android repository for downloading a zip called x86-25_r09.zip.

I downloaded this .zip file without the visual studio installer manually, and want to know where to extract this so the installer will skip over this step and continue with the rest of the installation.

Edit: I manually installed the file from here: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-25_r09.zip

Comment: Can you share any screenshots? Does this prevent your installation of Xamarin completely? Can you try to uncheck the `Google Android Emulator (API Level 25)` in the `Optional` section of the `Mobile development with C#` payload?

Comment: I have encountered simliar problem before, maybe it is the network's problem, so I install and uninstall until it completes without any errors. And you can report it  at [here](https://104.40.62.9/content/problem/141704/androidimage-arm-ap125.html)